# rosbuild vs catkin

Tags: ros, catkin, beginner, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ros and was wondering what exactly rosbuild and catkin are and what is the difference between the two.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52815/rosbuild-vs-catkin/) by [dptsrk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3957/dptsrk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2013-01-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Both are buildsystems, meaning they generate executable files from source files. Both are meant to build many individual projects in the right order with a single command (The main difference to other build systems and the reason ROS has a buildsystem of its own). With both, cmake does most of the work (with rosbuild that's the typical usage), whereas the catkin or rosbuild code itself mostly coordinates multiple builds.

You could use google to find pages describing both systems. Their main differences are described here:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin_or_rosbuild

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3